# UIColor SetFill doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, uicolor

In this code

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*(i+1), self.yShift+self.rectLen*10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*(i+1), self.yShift+self.rectLen*10+self.rectLen);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*i, self.yShift+self.rectLen*10+self.rectLen);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*i, self.yShift+self.rectLen*10);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*i, self.yShift+self.rectLen*10);
}
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*4, self.yShift+self.rectLen*10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*4, self.yShift+self.rectLen*10+self.rectLen);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*3, self.yShift+self.rectLen*10+self.rectLen);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.xShift+15+self.rectLen*self.width+self.rectLen*3, self.yShift+self.rectLen*10);
    [[UIColor cyanColor] setFill];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

Line with setFill method doesn't work. What might be the problem of this? Code is located in drawRect: method

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", do you mean there is something wrong with the drawing, or just the colors?  Fill is used for filling a path, stroke (color of the line) is used for stroking a path.  It seems like you're saying you want the line to appear cyan, which would mean you have to use setStroke on that color instead.

Comment: I want rectangle to appear cyan but it doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setFill isn't for Core Graphics drawing but for drawing like [myUIBezierPath fill];

Instead set the fill color and stroke color using:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor cyanColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
```

Also, the following line:

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

Will only *stroke* the path, since the drawing mode is set to kCGPathStoke. To fill it as well you should replace it with

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

If your path has holes in it or crosses itself you should use even-odd fill and stroke

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathEOFillStroke);
```

Comment: Ah... now I see... you are only stroking the path, not filling.. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you need to call the appropriate `CG*` methods to set the fill like David suggested, you need to actually perform the fill using the following after you set the fill and stroke properties:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Your code won't stroke the path. The path is cleared after each drawing operation so after the fill operation there will be no path left to stroke.

Comment: I may be wrong though... a second look at the documentation only mentions clearing the path when stroking, not filling ("As a side effect when you call this function, Quartz clears the current path." (from CGContextStrokePath))